# How do I make a second function continue using the file from the first function?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have two functions. The first function 'EdFile' loops through all text files in a directory, and then through all lines in each file, where the text is parsed into objects.

The second function 'SaveToTxt' appends the edited content back to a text file. The problem is the second function doesn't write it back to the files in function 1. Would any of you know how the second function would be able to "sync" up with each file from the first function, such that each file that gets parsed in function 1, gets constructed back in function 2?

Here is the buttons that allows me to edit and save the files.

```
<button @onclick="EdFile">Edit file</button>
<button @onclick="SaveToTxt">Save</button>
...
...
```

Code:

```
List<EditItems> items = new();
public void EdFile()
{
    foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"wwwroot\Files")) // all files in folder
    {
        foreach (var line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(file)) // every line in file
        {
            string[] values = line.Split(',');

            if (values.Length == 3)
            {
                items.Add(new EditItems
                    {
                        One = values[0],
                        Two = values[1],
                        Three = values[2]
                    });
            }
        }
    }
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
public void SaveToTxt()
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        sb.AppendLine($"{item.One},{item.Two},{item.Three}");
    }
    File.WriteAllText(@"wwwroot\Files\somefile.txt", sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Do you have control over the `EditItems` object? If so, just add a `FilePath` property and use that when updating.

Comment: @Lex how would it be implemented in SaveToTxt?

Comment: Actually, re-reading your question I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do. Are you trying to read all the lines from a bunch of different files and then write them all out to a single file? Or you're reading the values in, someone can edit those values, and then you want to write the edited values back to the original files they came from? Are you overwriting the existing data or just adding the edited stuff to the end of the file?

Comment: Right now I have the values displayed in each their text area where they can be edited. The origin file then gets overwritten when saved. The reason i'm reading from multiple files is because i got stuck and didn;t know how else i could get multiple files to select from, such that the selected file is the one that is parsed and the one that is overwriting the selected file when saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure if you are trying to write back to all the files, or if you are editing the values only from a single file and then you want to overwrite that file. Either way, presuming you can modify the `EditItems` class (if you can't then you may just have to extend it with your own class) you could do something like this:

```
public class EditItems
{
    public string One { get; set; }
    public string Two { get; set; }
    public string Three { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}

public SomeComponentClass
{    
    List<EditItems> items = new();
    public void EdFile()
    {
        // all files in folder
        foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"wwwroot\Files"))
        {
            // every line in file
            foreach (var line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(file)) 
            {
                string[] values = line.Split(',');
    
                if (values.Length == 3)
                {
                    items.Add(new EditItems
                        {
                            One = values[0],
                            Two = values[1],
                            Three = values[2],
                            FilePath = file,
                        });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void SaveToTxt()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // group the items collection by the files from 
        // which they were read
        var groups = items.GroupBy(x => 
            x.FilePath, (filePath, items) => 
                new { filePath, items);

        // now loop each of those groups and write the values 
        // back to the file they came from
        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            foreach (var item in group.items)
            {
                sb.AppendLine($"{item.One},{item.Two},{item.Three}");
            }
            File.WriteAllText(group.filePath, sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I very much appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: Do you know how it could be done if the values edited from a single file and then i want to overwrite that file?

Comment: @PianiDud You would have to implement some type of change tracking so that you can determine which values actually changed and then only update the file(s) from which those values were initially read.